# an Integral that should be doable:

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

```
Integrate[Cos[\[Beta]] Exp[I z Cos[\[Beta] - \[Alpha]]], {\[Beta], 0, 2 \[Pi]},Assumptions -> z \[Element] Reals]
```

---

correct answer is [ I think ]:

```
2 I Pi BesselJ[1, z] Cos[Alpha]
```

---

Asking for a friend  ;)

Comment: Is this Question about the Software Mathematica? If so please complement your Question with Code. Else [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions) satisfies your needs better.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: The first and second inputs are Mathematica code.

Comment: Try to exe the code, what result do you get?

Comment: Mathematica replies with original question after considerable delay. Using v10.1 on OS X.

Comment: I get `Syntax::sntxb: Expression cannot begin with "[Beta]-Cos[Alpha]".`, this indicates you have some trivial syntax errors. Pls consider reworking your code.

Comment: copy and paste issue:  [alpha] should just have read alpha, same with beta.

Comment: Lou - please see edits; now in correct code form.

Comment: Replacing `Exp[I ...]` with `Cos[...] + I Sin[...]` helps a bit. The Integral of the first summand is zero. The second appears to be `Pi`-periodic, but Mathematica seems to be struggling. Still investigating, but this is indeed more of a mathematics question, rather than Mathematica.

Comment: I think its a Mathematica issue. The "answer" I gave is actually correct, I think.

Comment: Powerful, as Mathematica may be, it is not an artificial intelligence and cannot always figure out the correct substitutions for evaluating any given integral. I don't think this merits being called "an issue". Sometimes it needs to be nudged in the right direction.

Comment: Not sure I agree. I think its an "issue" that it can't do it. Only by raising these "issues" in an otherwise fantastic tool will it progress and improve, I guess?

Comment: There'll always be an integral too hard for it. Writing up an answer right now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how to make Mathematica integrate this, but a lot is done by hand.

```
Cos[β] Exp[I z Cos[β - α]] == 
    Cos[β] Cos[z Cos[α - β]] +
    I Cos[β] Sin[z Cos[α - β]]
```

The integral of the first summand is zero. Make the substitution `γ == α - β` and expand the `Cos[β]` to `Cos[α] Cos[γ] + Sin[α] Sin[γ]`. Also note that the function is `Pi`-periodic. The integral then transforms to

```
2 I * Integrate[(Cos[α] Cos[γ] + Sin[α] Sin[γ]) * 
                     Sin[z Cos[γ]], {γ, α - Pi, α}]
```

The part with the sines is easy - `Sin[γ] d(γ) == -d(Cos[γ])`. This part also integrates to zero. Again, note that we are integrating over a full period of the function. Replace integration limits with `{0, Pi}`. So the integral simplifies to

```
2 I Cos[α] * Integrate[Cos[γ] Sin[z Cos[γ]], {γ, 0, Pi}]
```

and the integral here evaluates:

```
Integrate[Cos[γ] Sin[z Cos[γ]], {γ, 0, Pi}]
(* Pi BesselJ[1, z] *)
```

Therefore, your answer `2 I Pi BesselJ[1, z] Cos[α]` was correct.

Comment: Many thanks LLIAMnYP

Comment: Thanks for the accept, you're welcome. I'm not sure, though, if the question has a real answer. Yes, we have verified that this integral evaluates to what you thought it should evaluate to, but as-is, it is not doable by Mathematica. Like you said, maybe things will improve.

Comment: Somewhat more direct: `Integrate[Cos[β] Exp[I z Cos[β - α]] /. β -> β + α, {β, 0, 2 π}, Assumptions -> z ∈ Reals]` yields the OP's answer.  (By periodicity, the integral is invariant under translation.)

Comment: @MichaelE2, Thanks I didn't check at every step whether the integral evaluated.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - many thanks.